# Can any one tell me what this logcat is demanding for? Fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Right now i am trying to create one sample fragment program in android,so far i am following this [link](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android) for reference and i got the project from this site itself.
After imported of this project,i could not run this project and i am getting issues like the below logcat.

Can any one please tell me what the below logcat is demanding for? in android.

**LOGCAT**

```
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.survivingwithandroid.fragment/com.survivingwithandroid.fragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at com.survivingwithandroid.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    ... 11 more
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4831)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-30 10:54:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(22318):    ... 21 more
```

**layout-land/activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <fragment android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragPage" 
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="4"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-port/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<fragment android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout-port/linklist_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@+id/urls" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-port/row_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-port/web_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<WebView android:id="@+id/webPage"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is error in xml file.....

Comment: Post your XML layout and your code. Most probably, there is no `android:name="com.survivingwithandroid.fragment.YourFragmentHere"` inside your `<fragment>` tag.

Comment: Show your layout code.

Comment: @AndrewT.;@GrlsHu please visit my question again i've posted my layouts.

Comment: Name your frame  (Give it an ID) layout! While calling it to change fragments you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout code as you have used the `Fragment` layout you need to provide some class to load in that `Fragement` layout as below:

```
   <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragmentclass"
          android:id="@+id/listFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As there are two ways to implement the `Fragment`

- **Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.**

In this case, you can specify layout properties for the fragment as if it were a view. For example, here's the layout file for an activity with two fragments:

```
 <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragmentclass"
          android:id="@+id/listFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The `android:name` attribute in the `<fragment>` specifies the `Fragment` class to instantiate in the layout. When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each fragment specified in the layout and calls the `onCreateView()` method for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout.

- **Another is to define programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.**

You can then add a fragment using the `add()` method, specifying the fragment to add and the view in which to insert it.

For example:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: @GrlsHu i am using the fragment control on both layout-port and layout-land, have i to mention the "android:name" for both layout?

Comment: Yes you have to mention the name for both layouts.

Comment: Also in the second method, you can define a tag to represent the fragment. Later on you can use these tags for a lot of processing.

Comment: @AstralProjection Yes you are right. Thanks for sharing information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a name attribute for your fragments so that Android knows which fragment to load. That should contain the full name of your fragment class:

```
android:name="com.example.SomeFragment"
```

See more on [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout).

Answer (score 0):

You call a fragment like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Fragment1_3 fragment1_3 = new Fragment1_3();  
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragemnt1_2, fragment1_3, "Fragment1_3"); 
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Fragment1_3");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`R.id.fragemnt1_2` is the ID of the frame layout of the current fragment. Use that!

Your FrameLayout should have:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragemnt1_2" // This is referenced in the call fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragemnt1_2, fragment1_3, "Fragment1_3"); 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >
```